# Is there any point where failure to enforce a law would result in the law being invalidated?

Tags: united-states, enforceability

(Note: I am not a marijuana user. I'm just asking to learn about legal principles.)

For example, the current situation with marijuana is that it is legal in some states, but it is still federally illegal - however, the feds have declined to enforce this law so far.

Say this situation continued as-is for several decades. Then one day, the feds decided out of the blue to just arrest a bunch of marijuana users, even though they were in compliance with their state laws.

Is there any defense in the fact that the law went unenforced for decades? Could these defendants make an argument that the law had effectively been nullified? Do the feds have a duty to at least warn people if they are going to resume enforcement?

And a related question, say the feds did issue a warning that they were going to resume enforcement on (date). Marijuana user (A) decides to heed the warning and gets rid of all marijuana and paraphernalia prior to (date). Could (A) still be prosecuted for their actions prior to (date), as long as they were within the statute of limitations? This has the "feeling" of an ex post facto law - but technically, (A)'s actions were never federally legal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### [Desuetude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desuetude#)

Desuetude is a common and civil law legal principle that causes statutes, similar regulation, or legal principles to become unenforceable by long habit of non-enforcement.

This is an established, albeit rarely used, part of United States law and was affirmed as such by SCOTUS in [Poe v Ulman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe_v._Ullman) although the case was not ultimately decided on that basis.

It does not apply to the Constitution. It is also *not* a feature of English law due to the doctrine of Parliamentary supremacy - inaction by the executive cannot override the express wishes of the legislature, even for a law made hundreds of years ago.

The best explanation of it is in the decision of [Committee of Legal Ethics v Printz](https://casetext.com/case/commmittee-on-legal-ethics-v-printz) which Wikipedia summarises adequately as:

> 1. The statute proscribes only acts that are malum prohibitum (wrong because prohibited by statute) and not malum in se (intrinsically wrong);
> 2. There has been open, notorious and pervasive violation of the statute for a long period; and
> 3. There has been a conspicuous policy of nonenforcement of the statute.

That said, arguments for desuetude are rarely made and even more rarely successful.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there any defense in the fact that the law went unenforced for
> decades? Could these defendants make an argument that the law had
> effectively been nullified?

No.

The concept you are describing is called *desuetude*. But, while desuetude is a doctrine applied sometimes in contract and property rights cases involving private parties, it basically never prevails in cases about the enforcement of a duly enacted law. (@DaleM notes in [his answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/99345/9517), [one case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe_v._Ullman) where the doctrine was cited positively by the U.S. Supreme Court in *dicta*, but this doctrine was not the basis for its decision.)

An official statement from a government official with the authority to do so that the law will not be enforced, however, does have this effect.

The cases of *United States v. Laud*, 385 U.S. 475 (1967), *Cox v. Louisiana*, 379 U.S. 559 (1965), and *Raley v. Ohio*, 360 U.S. 423 (1959), stand for the proposition that a defendant may not be prosecuted for actions taken in good faith reliance upon authoritative assurances that the defendant will not be punished for those actions.

The reliance on official statements doctrine established by these cases, and the statements made by certain federal prosecutors related to marijuana offenses, not desuetude, is the reason that people can be comfortable that they will not be prosecuted for marijuana offenses that they have been told by federal prosecutors will not be enforced.

Non-enforcement for decades, followed by enforcement against a single individual who can prove that the prosecution against this individual was based upon an ulterior motive of a governmental official (basically a private grudge), can also sometimes be used to support an equal protection "class of one" defense, although this defense only extremely rarely prevails. *See* William D. Araiza, "[Irrationality and Animus in Class-of-One Equal Protection Cases](https://brooklynworks.brooklaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1055&context=faculty#:%7E:text=protection%20claims%20brou)" 34 Ecology Law Quarterly 493 (2007), citing and discussing *Village of Willowbrook v. Olech*, 528 U.S. 562 (2000), and some related cases.

> Do the feds have a duty to at least warn people if they are going to
> resume enforcement?

Only if there has been a prior official statement that it will not be enforced.

UPDATE:

The only example I can think of where desuetude might apply is the right to trial by combat in a state that incorporated by reference the common law of England as of July 4, 1776 (or something similar) to the extent not superseded by U.S. law. And, even that is a close call, and there is an argument that this is really a case of implicit repeal of that part of the common law and not desuetude.

Comment: Aren't there lots of arcane, obsolete laws on the books that probably have never had such official statements about non-enforcement? The government could just start enforcing these things if they wanted to?

Comment: https://www.buzzfeed.com/rhiannacampbell/weird-old-american-laws-you-wont-believe

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Although some of those laws would be infirm for other reasons (e.g. they violated a constitutional right).

Comment: @Barmar as we've seen after Roe v. Wade was overturned, many states had laws that became invalid when Roe v. Wade was decided, but they still kept them on the books. And when Roe v. Wade was overturned, those laws suddenly became valid again.

Comment: +1. Re: equal protection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_prosecution may also be of interest.

Comment: @ruakh Selection prosecution claims, so denominated, almost always lose. It is an even weaker argument than an equal protection class of one argument.

Comment: @ohwilleke: I'll take your word for it! I'm not giving legal advice here, I just thought that's relevant. :-)

Comment: @ruakh I mention it mostly because one subset of people who turn to Law.SE for advice for prisoners seeking to file post-conviction legal cases for which they have no right to a publicly funded lawyer (and other non-lawyers in their lives trying to be helpful to them). Indigent criminal defendants very commonly seize upon "selective prosecution" as something that they think is a legal defense that fits the facts of their case. I'm hoping to discourage readers in that position from doing down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Ah, makes sense; thanks for explaining!